# Getting a type of value from binding class without converter

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, telerik

I have a problem with getting a type of value from `Binding` class.

In my case I have a `AutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition` method on `RadPropertyGrid` in this method depends on type of binded value (I have this `Binding` by `e.PropertyDefinition.Binding`) I need to set a `DataTemplate`.
But because I don't know is it a boolean, text or collection I can set it(for example: for boolean I need a datatemplate with checkbox).

How can I get this `Type`?

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo= radPropertyGrid.Item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == e.PropertyDefinition.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();
Type bindingPropertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
```